# C# Replace a goto statement with an if-else

Tags: c#, loops, goto

I'm trying to replace this block of code with any other loop (I thought of while and do, but for some reason I didn't get the logic down entirely.

```
repeat:
   ... 
   if (condition)
   {
     goto repeat
   }
   else
   {
     ...
   }
```

Can someone help me out with the logic here? I saw a few posts about replacing goto statements, but they only relied on a single if with no else's.

The thing that is messing my thinking up is the fact that there isn't anything inside the if statement, just the goto. If I were to try to translate it to a while statement, it leaves me with this:

```
while (condition)
{
   // don't know what goes here since there is nothing but goto in the if statement
}
// else stuff
```

Thanks

Comment: `while(condition){ /*code*/ }`.. pretty straight-forward.

Comment: What is difficult about understanding this code for you?

Comment: The comment in the while condition is wrong. This is should be what you have between "repeat:" and "if (condition)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple `do`-`while` loop:

```
do
{
    // code between "repeat:" and the if here
} while (condition);

// else code here
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to go, because the condition check is at the end. This is only because within the if statement (near goto) is no code. +1

Comment: I edited your answer to make it a little more obvious what the `// ...` represents.

Comment: I was able to translate it thanks to Jeroen's explanation and editing. It makes sense now. Thanks :)